# gzstream compiling error, no such file or directory

Tags: c++, include

I've downloaded the gzstream classes for an assignment I have. Since I'm new to C++, I've ran the Makefile that comes with the classes and produced an gzstream.o file. This is all stored in the folder "gzstream". Now I have a main.cpp file, that has the following include.

```
#include "gzstream/gzstream.C"
```

And I get the following error

g++: error: gzstream.C: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `main.cpp` file against `gzstream` folder?

Comment: Are you sure you want to include `.C` file not `.h`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's in same directory as the gzstream folder

Comment: @Slyforce Is there a `gzstream.h` file under `gzstream` folder?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yes there is

Comment: @ALan It throws almost the same error, only that it doesn't find the .h file instead of the .C file